# fetch php file from js script (Stripe Checkout) 403 Error

Tags: php, javascript

Following stripe docs, I created 2 files in my theme directory (checkout.php & checkout.js)  I can't figure out how to fetch checkout.php from checkout.js without getting a 403 error

Contents of the files:
JS:

```
// This is your test publishable API key.
const stripe = Stripe(" test-publish-key-goes-here ");

initialize();

// Create a Checkout Session as soon as the page loads
async function initialize() {
  const response = await fetch("https://example.com/wp-content/themes/hello-elementor-child/checkout.php", {
    method: "POST",
  });

  const { clientSecret } = await response.json();

  const checkout = await stripe.initEmbeddedCheckout({
    clientSecret,
  });

  // Mount Checkout
  checkout.mount('#checkout-stripe-custom');
}
```

PHP:

```
require_once WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/stripe-lib/stripe-php/init.php';

$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient( STRIPE_SK_TEST );
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$YOUR_DOMAIN = 'https://example.com';

$checkout_session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
  'ui_mode' => 'embedded',
  'line_items' => [[
    # Provide the exact Price ID (e.g. pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
    'price' => 'a-stripe-product-id',
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
  'mode' => 'payment',
  'return_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
]);

echo json_encode(array('clientSecret' => $checkout_session->client_secret));
```

Comment: you shouldn't be making AJAX requests directly to PHP files in your theme, you need to use a REST API endpoint or at least a legacy admin AJAX API. If you don't then WP won't be loaded and there'll be lots of security issues to work around. Look up https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/ and `register_rest_route` to create a pretty URL you can make requests to in JS with `fetch` that returns JSON. It's very likely you're getting a 403 because your host is blocking direct requests to PHP files in your theme and they're correct to do so